# Get information about MAC address

Tags: router, wifi, mac-address, network-security

My router (FritzBox 7330) shows tons of errors about a device that continuously try to connect to my network:

```
23.12.19    10:17:07    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:16:55    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:16:43    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:16:30    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:16:18    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:16:06    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:15:54    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:15:42    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
23.12.19    10:15:30    Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida. Indirizzo MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
```

"Registrazione del dispositivo wireless fallita: chiave wireless non valida." means: "Registration of wireless device failed: wireless key not valid.".

"Indirizzo MAC" means "MAC address".

This happens during the whole day. Every few seconds this device tries to connect - and fails.

Of course I double checked all my devices (PC, smartphones, IoT, etc...) and none is missing. 
Unfortunately, my FritzBox doesn't allow me to block just a MAC address. It can only do the opposite: enable the known devices only - this is not what I want.

Question: may I "harvest" more information about this device knowing only:

- its MAC address
- it's a WiFi device
- it tries to connect to my network

What should I do?

Comment: A downvote without any explanation doesn't allow me to improve the question. Please tell me what is my mistake.

Comment: The leading digits from MAC addresses are usually vendor specific. A MAC address lookup may allow you to find the vendor and help track down the culprit. - please note that you should try to post error messages in English rather than localized

Comment: @HermanB, question updated with the translation. I didn't know that the leading digits of the MAC addresses are vendor specific! I found something useful with the lookup - thanks! Yours should be an answer rather a comment.

Comment: Hi, I would got a device that can block by MAC, as if hes in range, he can try to bruteforce your password for ages. Changing the channel to the 5ghz might help if its a older device.